# What can I do to fix the java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a hangman (the game) program, and I have an encoded phrase that is shown as asterisks to the user. When the user guesses a correct letter, I'm trying to change the encoded asterisks phrase so that it changes the one asterisk to the the user input letter. I'm using the indexOf method, but it keeps outputting a -1 and giving me the

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
String index out of range -1
```

Here is the code:

```
 System.out.print("Enter your next guess: ");
 String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine();

 System.out.println("You guessed " + userGuess.toUpperCase() + ".");
 System.out.println();
 if(phrase.contains(userGuess.toUpperCase())) {

   System.out.println("This is present in the secret phrase.");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Number of wrong guesses so far: " + wrongGuesses);
   int index = phrase.indexOf(userGuess);
   System.out.print(index);
   encodedPhrase = (encodedPhrase.substring(0, index) + userGuess + encodedPhrase.substring(index + 1));
```

Comment: `phrase.indexOf(userGuess);` return -1 which mean it was not found. Change it to `phrase.indexOf(userGuess).toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the string contains `userGuess.toUpperCase()` that doesn't mean it contains `userGuess` too. You'll get -1 when it doesn't.

A simple fix:

```
String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

And then you can remove all the other `.toUpperCase()` calls, as the string is already uppercased, once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

`userGuess` might not be part of your phrase as per your statement:

```
int index = phrase.indexOf(userGuess);
```

[indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) would return -1 if `userGuess` is not part of `phrase`. So before using substring, try using:

```
if (index < 0) {
   //userGuess not part of phrase
} else {
    //do get substring and other business logic
}
```

Also you are trying to do contains with `userGuess.toUpperCase()`, other way to avoid it would be:

```
int index = phrase.indexOf(userGuess.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: The phrase I'm testing out is "Psycho", and whenever I input "P", I still get this error even though it's part of the string.

Comment: @Hector You should convert string to upper case and then do `indexOf` on upper cased string. NRitH, i already answered that.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly your Phrase is in Capitals.

When checking for the userguess `if(phrase.contains(userGuess.toUpperCase()))` you are converting it to uppercase, but when checking for the index `int index = phrase.indexOf(userGuess);` you are not.

try to get the index after converting the userGuess to uppercase as in your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You verified that the *uppercase* version of the user's guess is in your string, but later your `indexOf()` check is *not* checking the uppercase version. Convert the user's guess to uppercase, and *then* check whether it's in the string and what its index is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to covert both input character and word to either upper case or lowercase.

Instead of :

```
phrase.contains(userGuess.toUpperCase())
```

write :

`phrase.toUpperCase().contains(userGuess.toUpperCase())`